# Issue with a simple assertion in FStar

Tags: fstar

I've just started to study FStar. I'd like to express the fact that for every natural number there exists a bigger one.

```
let _ = assert (forall (m:nat). exists (n: nat). n > m)
```

It fails and I'd like to know why. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quantified formulas such as the one you have here are handled, by default, using Z3's heuristics for pattern-based quantified instantiation. You can read more about Z3 patterns here: https://rise4fun.com/Z3/tutorialcontent/guide#h28
 and https://github.com/FStarLang/FStar/wiki/Quantifiers-and-patterns

In short, you need to help F* and Z3 find a witness for the existential quantifier. One way to do it is like this:

```
let lem (m:nat)
  : Lemma (exists (n:nat). n > m)
  = assert (m + 1 > m)
```

which proves a lemma that for any `m:nat` there exists an `n:nat` greater than `m`. Its proof to F*+Z3 hints that `m + 1` is a good witness to choose for `n`.

You can turn an lemma like this into a quantified assertion in many ways. See FStar.Classical for some examples of that. For example, this works:

```
let _ =
  FStar.Classical.forall_intro lem;
  assert (forall (m:nat). exists (n: nat). n > m)
```

Here's another approach that avoids defining an intermediate lemma, but uses an intermediate assertion instead.

```
let _ =
  assert (forall (m:nat). m + 1 > m);
  assert (forall (m:nat). exists (n: nat). n > m)
```

Comment: Nik, thank you for your kind reply. Regarding the last approach, I've refined 'm' in the first term as {m > 10} and as {m > 11} in the second term to express the fact that there's a bigger n for all m > 11. The assertion failed. Could you show me how to fix it?